# Magento2 What determines State Code and Title's Square Bracketed Value in Order Status Grid

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, order-status

1. What determines ***State Code and Title***'s Square Bracketed Value in
   **Order Status Grid** in the below screenshot. It doesn't appear to be
   the default status for that state?
2. If it is coming out of the database or config, **where is it stored**?
3. Does the Square Bracketed title **display anywhere on the frontend or in
   order processing in the backend**?

[image: ***enter image description here***]

Comment: A helicopter view of the grid seems to suggest that its the first status alphabetically that is assigned to the state - if that is true then as I can see no purpose for that information, it would seem to be a bug and the core developer intended it to be the title of the default status? should I perhaps open a bug report??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the Square Bracketed title displays only on this grid.

Take a look: `vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Status/Grid/Column/State.php` , we can see the function which used for decorating this column:

```
public function decorateState($value, $row, $column, $isExport)
{
        if ($value) {
            $cell = $value . '[' . $this->_config->getStateLabel($value) . ']';
        } else {
            $cell = $value;
        }
        return $cell;
}
```

*vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Config.php*

```
protected function _getState($state)
{
    foreach ($this->_getCollection() as $item) {
        ......
    }

}

protected function _getCollection()
{
    if ($this->collection == null) {
        $this->collection = $this->orderStatusCollectionFactory->create()->joinStates();
    }
    return $this->collection;
}
```

As we can see,  **table `sales_order_status` will join with `sales_order_status_state` table to find the State which the status is assigned to. This column will get the Label data from this result.**

Comment: Thanks @KhoaTruongDinh - as there will be more than status assigned to that state it will only grabbing the first label from that join and hence it is coming as the first alphabetically, I would imagine the core developer intended it to be the title of the default status? - does that smell like a bug to you?

Comment: @WayneTheisinger tomorrow, I will try to print the join collection. And, give you my feedback.

Comment: @Wayne Theisinger i think it is not a bug. Magento will get all the statutes first, for each status, it will do a join collection to find the State.

Comment: in which case I'm baffled as what it supposed to represent... - Oh well at least we can be sure it won't muck up what I'm trying to do... thanks for your help.